# Derogatory term for people from places like San Francisco

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, offensive-language, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a derogatory term for people from liberal metropolitain areas who think they are better educated and more enlightened than those from rural, conservative areas.

Carthage, TX is to redneck as San Francisco, CA is to ______________.

EDIT:

In response to comments below, I feel I must add that I do not believe the people of SF "think they are better educated and more enlightened than those from rural, conservative areas."

If I did believe that, I wouldn't be asking this question now would I? BECAUSE I WOULD KNOW ALL THE DERAGATORY TERMS.

Comment: How is this different from a question asking for an inflammatory term you could use to disparage people from Africa?  This isn't the "help me with name-calling and pissing people off" Stack Exchange site. This is the site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts where we build up a library of expert answers. I don't see how your question fits with those goals, let alone with any goals of human decency.  Helping folks curse others is not why we're here.

Comment: @tchrist It seems to me that the OP was asking for the antonym of "redneck" on the political spectrum, which seems like a reasonable question to me. Also, I did not seriously expect to see **ALL CAPS BOLD FLAMING** from an experienced user here, let alone a moderator.

Comment: @MarchHo [Please see this meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4842/2085).

Comment: @SOJ Is the duplicate a match?

Comment: The answers are related but the question is not what I'm asking.

Comment: @SOJ Sounds like it's a duplicate then. Often people ask questions differently but the same answers show up. We leave the duplicate as a sign-post so that others thinking of the question in that other way can still find the same set of answers either way.

Comment: @tchrist (I'm probably biased, but) while "city slicker" IMO applies to both questions, that's because it has both senses (don't have skills for rural life, are arrogant about being city dwellers), but most of the other answers here won't apply to the other (hipsters, elitist, etc. do  not imply a lack of skills needed for rural life). Essentially, it's just one answer that's common.

Comment: @tchrist  While derogatory terms are by nature offensive, you know not the intentions of the OP. Writers often portray characters as offensive. You are right, this is no different to harmful words towards racial or religious groups, but It's only offensive if you choose to be offended by it. Most of the users of a site like this are mature enough to see that this does not show explicit intent to be offensive, so it is not a harmful question.

Comment: @SOJ My complaint is that your title characterizes the word as meaning "people from places like San Francisco" and the question body characterizes it as meaning "people who have a particular set of views". The combination of these two statements entails that people from SF have this set of views. That is an act of prejudice: you're concluding that people behave in a certain way based only on where they live.

Comment: @David Richerby that was the point of the wording of the question: to impress upon you, a potential answerer, the perspective of the people who utter the derogatory terms that I'm looking for so that you can better answer the question.

Comment: @SOJ what's you intended use for the word, are you doing some writing or is it just so you have ammo for twitter to talk smack?

Answer (score 31):

## City slicker

> *informal*, *derogatory*
> A person with the sophistication and values generally associated with
> urban dwellers. ([Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/city_slicker))
>
> ---
>
> someone who lives in a city and does not understand what life outside a city is like ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/city%20slicker))

While the usual emphasis is on the lack of knowledge about rural life and skills needed there, it also applies to people who are arrogant about living in the city. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_slicker):

> *City slicker* was derisively given to people from the urban Eastern United States when they took on an attitude that their lifestyle and
> access to the culture of city life gave them superior intelligence.
> [...]
>
> The archetypal city slicker is depicted as a spoiled, selfish, lazy,
> rich person who considers people living on farms to be poor and
> ignorant.

And it certainly is derogatory like "redneck".

Comment: I think this is less political than what the OP is looking for, though. *City slicker* is usually just a town mouse/country mouse type thing. People from SF (at least stereotypically) also think they're more *morally* enlightened.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Perhaps say "high-bred city-slickers" vs "inbred rednecks" to suggest a comparison of (sexual, at least) mores? I wish there was more context...

Comment: What I like best about this answer is that it has one subtle parallelism with *redneck* in that both terms are sometimes worn as badges of pride both members of the groups to which they may reasonably be applied, as a way to undermine their derisive qualities.

Answer (score 29):

Recently in the United States, I've heard the term **coastal elite** growing in use.

The term is referenced in *Salon* in an article titled ['“Real Americans” vs. “coastal elites”: What right-wing sneers at city dwellers really mean'](http://www.salon.com/2016/11/20/real-americans-vs-coastal-elites-what-right-wing-sneers-at-city-dwellers-really-mean/)

> Then, there is the popular expression “**coastal elites**” — an all-encompassing term for any educated professional who lives in a major city in California or along the Eastern seaboard.

Since many U.S. liberal cities appear on the east or west coast, referring to urban people, professionals, figures or pundits as ***coastal*** in a derogatory way seems to be growing in popularity among those who wish to disparage such types.

I live in Chicago, in the American Midwest. Although many people here refer to "The coast of Lake Michigan," Chicagoans would only qualify as "coastal" in a political sense by figurative extension of the urban elite epithet.

Answer (score 21):

Currently, it's libtard. If they were young, possibly hipster.

See for example [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=libtard) or [Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Libtard) (the place to go for derogatory terms).

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. While vulgar, it does fit the premise of the question. There could be a little more exposition perhaps though.

Comment: Could use a reference, so we know that it was not just made up by Joly.

Comment: @bendl I downvoted because the usage is generally much broader than the OP's request.  "Libtard", in common usage, refers to literally anyone who is left-leaning.  I had never seen the first definition in the linked UrbanDictionary article, and had never seen the word used that way, but now that I see that that was a usage, I will retract my downvote.

Comment: I feel like "libtard" isn't quite the same as "redneck"

Comment: Another good down vote reason is that this word alludes to an offensive slur, unlike *redneck*.

Comment: Redneck is absolutely an offensive slur.

Comment: @Davo It certainly once was, and still is in some situations, depending on the context. However, there exists enormous swaths of the united states where redneck life and redneck culture is celebrated. It is a great example of the reclaiming of a word.

Answer (score 11):

**elitist**

> noun
>
> 3. a person having, thought to have, or professing superior intellect or talent, power, wealth, or membership in the upper echelons of society: *He lost a congressional race in Texas by being smeared as an Eastern elitist.*
> 4. a person who believes in the superiority of an elitist class.

[from Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elitist)

For example, from "[San Francisco Man In Massive 'Wife Swap' Fallout](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/02/21/san-francisco-man-in-mass_n_168797.html)", *Huffington Post*, March 24, 2009:

> Fowler’s stint on the ABC reality show last month, in which he called a rural Missouri woman spending two weeks in his San Francisco home stupid and simple, has made him famous in the worst way.

...

> Three weeks later, Fowler’s “Wife Swap” antics are still a YouTube sensation, with at least 10 postings from the show’s Jan. 30 episode displayed on the Web site, most with headings such as “ridiculous elitist” and “elitists gone wild.”

...

> His performance evoked a stereotype of the San Francisco elitist liberal — the tree-hugging do-gooder who acts morally superior while putting down others.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  Believing someone of superior intellect should be in a different class is different from someone believing that they *have* that superior intellect needed to be in an elite class.

Comment: @Physics-Compute I may be missing a subtlety here, but in my interpretation that is equivalent to "3. a person ... professing superior intellect ...".

Comment: I may be hinging more on the literal meaning of elite+ist, where either he *is* an elite or *advocates* for elitism.  Calling someone/yourself an elite does not make them one. Unless the target actually does have superior intellect, a more accurate phrase would be, "Pretend elite/elitist" or "Counterfeit elite/elitist" if the intent is to show that the person *thinks* of themself as an elite but is not in reality.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be technically correct, but oftentimes in everyday speech such people are branded as Yuppies.

yuppie
[yuhp-ee]
noun (often initial capital letter)
a young, ambitious, and well-educated city-dweller who has a professional career and an affluent lifestyle.

Source:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yuppie

Answer (score 5):

The use of **cosmopolitan** as an insult in this vein is explored in this article:

http://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/08/03/the-ugly-history-of-stephen-millers-cosmopolitan-epithet-215454

> When TV news viewers saw Trump adviser Stephen Miller accuse Jim Acosta of harboring a “cosmopolitan bias” during Wednesday’s news conference, they might have wondered whether he was accusing the CNN White House reporter of an excessive fondness for the cocktail made famous on “Sex and the City.” It’s a term that’s seldom been heard in American political discourse. But to supporters of the Miller-Bannon worldview, it was a cause for celebration. Breitbart, where Steve Bannon reigned before becoming Trump’s chief political strategist, trumpeted Miller’s “evisceration” of Acosta and put the term in its headline. So did white nationalist Richard Spencer, who hailed Miller’s dust-up with Acosta as “a triumph.”

Comment: It might be good to note that the word cosmopolitan is considered a dog-whistle for white-nationalists. It was a word used by Hitler and Stalin. [Source](https://www.pri.org/stories/2017-08-03/cosmopolitan-dog-whistle-word-once-used-nazi-germany-and-communist-russia)

Comment: Wow, I never knew Cosmo was a KKK publication. Here I thought they were just peddling makeup and sex.

Comment: It might be good to note that the word cosmopolitan is not the sole property of white nationalists, and casual association fallacies are bereft of merit. Oh, and Stephen Miller is Jewish.

Comment: ***Cosmopolitan*** is a perfectly respectable word meaning - per OED sense 1 (with various other related senses - none of them disparaging:) *1. Belonging to all parts of the world; not restricted to any one country or its inhabitants.
1848   J. S. Mill Princ. Polit. Econ. II. iii. xvii. 113   Capital is becoming more and more cosmopolitan.
1865   G. Grote Plato I. iv. 151   The mixed and cosmopolitan character of the Alexandrine population.
1869   R. Semmes Adventures Afloat ii. 670   They were of the cosmopolitan sailor class.*

Answer (score 5):

In Australia such people may be referred to as 'latte sipping lefties' or 'latte-sippers'.  This phrase is mildly derogatory.

"[LATTE-SIPPING LEFTIES UNITE
‘Latte sipping leftie’ is an insult often thrown around by conservatives, but loving your coffee and having a defined palate is nothing to be ashamed of — provided you're ethical about it.](https://greens.org.au/magazine/national/latte-sipping-lefties-unite)"

Urban Dictionary has a listing for 'latte sipper' which I have not linked to as it contains expletives and strongly offensive language.

The phrase 'latte sipping/er' is often used in the Australian political discourse to refer to the extreme left and their employees/supporters. It implies that the person is out of touch with the majority for whom a latte is neither affordable nor available in their location.

Comment: Just to be clear - the implication is that a latte is unavailable to the majority.  In actuality you can buy barista coffee in all but the most remote locations within Australia.

Comment: It's there, but how much does it cost? In the US, this evokes the daily $4-5 (US) Starbucks latte of the blindly privileged.

Answer (score 4):

**elite**

It's a step or two removed from the dictionary meaning, but I've heard it used in derogatory terms in Australian, British and US English to describe city dwellers with a left-leaning world view. It strongly implies that these people are distrustful because they are intelligent, cultured and out-of-touch with the "common man". It's generally used to deride someone who is more concerned with lofty ideals like human rights, the environment and foreign affairs than more "commonly" held concerns, like immigration, housing affordability or casual racism.

Most bizarrely, it's a label that has been propagated by right-wing media pundits and politicians who live a far more privileged existence and are unfalteringly guilty of every negative implication they make against those they label.

Comment: Especially the term "liberal elite". Usage seems to have increased dramatically in the U.S. since the 2016 elections. Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_elite

Comment: This is ... a really interesting interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

***Literati*** or perhaps ***Intelligentsia***

Literati: the educated class
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literati

Intelligentsia: intellectuals who form an artistic, social, or political vanguard or elite
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligentsia

Neither is explicitly derogatory, but they do carry overtones of derision particularly in this context.

Answer (score 1):

**Conceited** : having or showing an excessively high opinion of oneself ([Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceited))

**Vainglorious**: [boastful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boastful) -> a statement expressing excessive pride in oneself ([Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglorious))

**Self-important**: an exaggerated estimate of one's own importance; arrogant or pompous behavior ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-importance)) (see also: **self-applauding**)

**Know-it-all**: one who claims to know everything; also one who disdains advice ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/know-it-all)) (see also: **stuck-up**)

**Swollen-headed**: [arrogant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrogant), conceited ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swollen-headed)) (see also **big-headed**)

With a more indirect approach I would also recommend: **Patronizing**, **Pretentious**, **Braggart**

**EDIT**: A user pulled to my attention the lack of cosmopolitan connotations of the prior suggestions. As so I would like to suggest:

**[Urbanite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urbanite)** : a person who lives in a city

There are other options that culturally might make sense although can be seen as gender specific. Such is the case of [Corinthian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Corinthian) or [Mondaine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mondaine). It might also work to imply a lesser than apparent cultural importance perhaps by using a word such as [townie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/townie).

Comment: These only address the pejorative aspects of the question so far. Would you  please explain why they especially pertain to people from places like San Francisco?

Comment: @Tonepoet "people [...] who think they are better educated and more enlightened than [...]" and than the OP gave an example of San Francisco (which I assume could be from anywhere). Applying to the example: "Carthage, TX is to redneck as San Francisco, CA is to know-it-all" Does it not cover the apparent intentions of the OP?

Comment: Not quite. [Redneck](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=redneck) has certain regional connotations. It's associated with the *rural south*, so  the counterpart insult should at least have metropolitan connotations to make it fit S.F. just as well as redneck does Carthage Texas. Since your words can be equally applied to anybody from anywhere without such bias, they do not seem to be as good of a match.

Comment: @Tonepoet I see your point. I don't think I can add much to the other answers but I gave it try. I've edited the answer to ensure its on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested **Coastal Elite** which, while accurate, I don't think has the same derogatory connotations as *redneck*. I'd suggest instead **Hipster**, for young people who are over-educated and under-experienced, who think they're better and more tolerant than everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain the polite term would be ***metropolitan*** another might be ***urbane***. .

*Most members of Tony Blair's cabinet were people of metropolitan outlook and taste*.
*The professional class in Saudi Arabia are people of a perfectly urbane outlook*.

***Metropolitan*** - OED sense 4.

> 4. A native or inhabitant of a metropolis or large city; a person who has metropolitan ideas, manners, etc.
>
> 1795   A. Hughes Jemima I. 83   You are a Paisley by nature as well as
>   by birth, and incapable of becoming a worthy metropolitan.
>
> 1815   J. Jekyll in Bentham's Wks. (1843) X. 486   To so inveterate a
>   metropolitan as myself this is no grievance.
>
> 1882   E. O'Donovan Merv Oasis II. liv. 407   The people at Merv
>   considered themselves altogether as metropolitans.
>
> 1987   A. Brien Lenin ii. 95   I could not believe that these
>   sophisticated metropolitans, all of them Petersburg graduates, could
>   be so..obtuse.
>
> 1996   Independent 20 Aug. ii. 2 (heading)    The brave new
>   metropolitans.

Answer (score 0):

"Liberal elite" doesn't explicitly reference coastal areas, but is suggestive of the city-dwelling left who look down on "red state bumpkins".  If you want to reflect the financially well off, you might consider "limousine liberal"

Answer (score 0):

**Yuppie**

It's an anagram for "Young Urban Proffesional"

From [dictionary.com...](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yuppie)

> noun, (often initial capital letter)
>
> 1. a young, ambitious, and well-educated city-dweller who has a professional career and an affluent lifestyle.

It has a history:

Jerry Rubin was a political activist who eventually made a bunch of money by investing in Apple.  His followers were self-dubbed "yippies", and "yuppies" was the degradation of the term.

[wikipedia.org...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuppie)

Comment: This is a decent start to the answer, but it does nothing to show the pejorative nature of the word. Indeed, based upon this answer, you might even be inclined to think it is a *compliment*, since every trait mentioned in the definition like a positive one. I think you should include some quotations that make the analogy to redneck more obvious, perhaps by comparing usages of "damn rednecks" to "damn yuppies". Until this answer is improved, I will be voting against it because of the potential confusion, but please let me know when you do improve it, so I can reconsider how it should be rated.

Comment: @Tonepoet it's only your opinion that you think these traits are good.

Answer (score -2):

***Metrolitist***, perhaps?

Not a word I've heard ever, but do you see what I did there ;-) ? (an elision of *metropolitan* and *elitist*)

Comment: -1. It sounds like you literally made up this word on the fly. If I am mistaken, please provide evidence that this word is in common use.

Comment: @MarchHo - guilty as charged!  This question is inviting suggestions.  A new word seemed a reasonable offer.  Are (rationalised) neologisms against the rules?

Comment: @Dan neologisms tend not to be a good fit here. At the least controversial.

Comment: @Mitch - seems to be my middle name at the moment.